# endianess-check with boost differ compared to result by small code

Tags: c++, boost, endianness

Hi All
I am doing some preliminary checking to see whether my system is big-endian or little-endian.
In LInux it should be little-endian by default, but I just wanted to double check.
I used 2 approaches

1. using boost endian support
2. using some code I found in the web

I used the following static assertion

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(!BIG_ENDIAN);
```

that fails during compile time, so I though..mmhh...is my system big endian?
This is the error I have

```
error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type 
boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>’
```

If I do a test using some code like the one below, it confirm that the system is little-endian.
Do you know what I am doing wrong and it I am using Boost macro correctly?

```
bool is_big_endian_v3(){

    long x = 0x34333231;
    char *y = (char *) &x;

    if(std::strncmp(y,"1234",4)){
        printf("Big Endian");
        return true;
    }else{
        printf("Little Endian");
        return false;
    }
    std::runtime_error ex("I cannot be here");
    throw ex;

}
```

Answer (score 8):

The Boost library has changed and the code in the previous answer now (July 2019) generates deprecation messages and suggests the following:

```cpp
#include <boost/predef/other/endian.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
#if BOOST_ENDIAN_BIG_BYTE
    std::cout << "Big endian." << std::endl;
#elif BOOST_ENDIAN_LITTLE_BYTE
    std::cout << "Little endian." << std::endl;
#else
    std::cout << "Unknown endian." << std::endl;
#endif
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`BIG_ENDIAN` is not defined by Boost. If you look at the file

```
#include <boost/detail/endian.hpp>
```

you'll see that the macros defined there are `BOOST_BIG_ENDIAN`, `BOOST_LITTLE_ENDIAN`, or `BOOST_PDP_ENDIAN`. That means you need to revise your check to be:

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(!defined(BOOST_BIG_ENDIAN));
```

or, better:

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(defined(BOOST_LITTLE_ENDIAN));
```

Edit:

The above is not macro expanded as I expected, so I'd suggest to use

```
#if !defined(BOOST_BIG_ENDIAN) 
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(false);
#endif
```

instead. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but when I write the code the compiler tells me the following error: ‘BOOST_BIG_ENDIAN’ was not declared in this scope.a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression
template argument 1 is invalid. I also cannot find any defined keyword

Comment: Have you written `!defined(BOOST_BIG_ENDIAN)` and not just `!BOOST_BIG_ENDIAN`? Otherwise it's difficult to tell from here without seeing a small, but selfcontained example.

Comment: Hi. I copied and pasted exactly what you did wrote. Below my code in the main.cpp

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cppunit/extensions/TestFactoryRegistry.h>
#include <cppunit/ui/text/TestRunner.h>
#include <boost/detail/endian.hpp>
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>

BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(!defined(BOOST_BIG_ENDIAN));

Comment: I edited my answer above to give a solution that actually works.